# Accent MySQL-Flex/ZendFramework

Tags: mysql, actionscript-3, apache-flex, zend-framework, diacritics

In my table the Collation is:latin1_swedish_ci (but i tried UTF8_unicode too).
In my flex application when it shows the table,it displays it correct,with all accent and pointing correct,but in the table is like :" Ã© Ã§ Ã£o Ã©a ".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an encoding problem to me. Check the headers of your webpage, the charset in you html head, the encoding of your files.    Have a look at the [IConv](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php) functions, they are more powerful than utf8_en/decode. If you're looking for a more specific answer, you have to provide more details.

Andreas

Comment: Hmm, the only html i have is the index, wich loads the flex application,in there the is "utf-8".